# C# Global Mouse Hook Problems

Tags: c#

I made C# global mouse hook and it is working good, and I'm using it as auto clicker, which automatically clicks when left mouse is pressed. Obviously, I use mouse hook to make it, but now my autoclicker clicks just 1 time and stops. I think I know why is that but I don't know how to fix it, but here is the code:

```
private void OnMouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        label8.Text = "true";
        clicker.Enabled = true;
    }
}

private void OnMouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    label8.Text = "false";
    clicker.Enabled = false;
}

private void clicker_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

What I think happens is: It detects mouse is down, and it enables timer. Then it runs `clicker_Tick` which makes `mouse_event` which simulates mouse down and mouse up and when mouse is up mousehook detects it and does: `clicker.Enabled = false;`

Comment: ..what exactly is the question?

Comment: fix that it clicks only 1 time

Answer (score 1):

Your ticker is performing the `LEFTUP` command, which will trigger the `OnMouseUp` event and finally disable the ticker.

So you should use another key to stop the ticker, e.g with the right mouse button:

```
private void OnMouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        label8.Text = "false";
        clicker.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I know, but I need to simulate mouseclick, so how I fix it?

Comment: @Zyhes To simulate mouse click you can use `SendMessage` function from `WinAPI` instead.

Comment: chade_ I know that works, but I want to use only left click.

Comment: @m.rogalski, I tried to simulate mouse click with SendMessage but it clicked still only 1 time. Maybe I used the wrong SendMessage, so can you give Example of your SendMessage?

Comment: @Zyhes You have to send your mouse commands to the other window `SendMessage(otherProcess.MainWindow.Handle, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, wParam, lParam);Sleep(10);SendMessage(otherProcess.MainWindow.Handle, WM_LBUTTONUP, wParam, lParam);` If you send it to your window ( where you have your logic ) this wont work because you're stopping the timer right away.

Comment: Can you give whole thing not only SendMessage, DllImports too